# How rotate image portrait to landscape in view page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, image-rotation

I have more images in view pager, I want to rotate the image from portrait to landscape and landscape to portrait. I have already loaded images into view pager but I don't know how to change selected image screen orientation.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: view.setRotation(180); . Try this if works